# How do I redirect debug output in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, textbox, output

At the moment I write a lot of status messages out using the following:

```
Debug.Writeline("This is my status message");
```

I would like to be able to create a method that allows me to either output messages via `Debug` or redirect them to a textbox in my UI. However, the Debug and Textbox objects are not compatible. How can I do this in such a way that the caller can use the same message to generate output and let the calling method decide where to send it (i.e., to Debug, the UI, or even a log file)?

Comment: Use `Trace`, or something like log4net.

Comment: If you're averse to third-party logging libraries, here's a suggested way to create a [generic Logger extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377858/suggest-design-almost-every-object-in-app-has-loggger)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class derived from `TraceListener`, as described in the accepted answer to [Trace listener to write to a text box (WPF application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389264/trace-listener-to-write-to-a-text-box-wpf-application).

Note: The accepted answer details how to create the custom trace listener for C# WinForms, despite the question being about WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own logging class that bridge's your debugging class

```
interface ILog {
   public void Log();
}

public DebugLog : ILog {
  public DebugLog(Debug d) {} //ctor that takes Debug Object
  public void Log(){}
}

public WindowLog : ILog {
  public WindowLog(Text t) {} //ctor that takes window log
  public void Log(){}
}
```

Comment: I'd make those methods static, just so I don't have to remember to new up the `Log` class every time.

Comment: Is there a way to do this polymorphically, so I can pass in the Textbox.Text member or Debug object and somehow use the same method with both?  I'm not sure if I am explaining myself well enough since I woke up way too early today and I am NOT a morning person. :)